# What is the exact scriptural meaning of Shraddha?

Tags: scripture, sanskrit, terminology

In chapter 4 verse 39 of Geetha, lord Krishna told that a person with Shraddha achieves gnanam.

In this context what is the exact meaning of Shraddha according to scriptures?

Comment: It will be better if you put a reference to the chapter number and verse so that the context is well understood, as the word "Shraddha" might appear multiple times in Geeta.

Answer (score 2):

The word श्रद्धा (śraddhā) [means](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=ia&tran_input=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%BE&direct=se&anz=100) "faith" or "belief".

In [BG 4.39](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=4&field_nsutra_value=39&htrskd=1&httyn=1&htshg=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1), the word **श्रद्धावान्** is derrived from श्रद्धा which means:

> The man who is full of faith

Comment: How is faith defined?

Comment: @Wikash_ faith means *strong belief* or *complete trust*..

Comment: So assuming without proof.

Comment: @Wikash_ Yeah, there exists un-provable phenomenon. So, shradda is necessary in such cases.